# How to use subprocess piping in python

Tags: python

I have this:

```
$ cat waitforinput.sh 

#!/bin/sh
while read line
do
    echo $line
done
```

I do this:

```
>>> p1 = subprocess.Popen("/home/abc/waitforinput.sh", shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

>>> for i in xrange(1000):
...     p1.stdin.write("this is a good idea")
```

But when I do this now, I see no output:

```
>>> for i in p1.stdout:
...     print i
...
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a newline:

```
p1.stdin.write('this is a good idea\n')
```

Simple explanation: The shell script you are running expects a full line with a newline character at the end, that's how it knows that the line is finished.

Note: Sometimes you will even have to add a `p1.stdin.flush()` due to buffering.

Comment: That was true, but why did newline make such a huge difference? Please explain.

Comment: @abc: Your shell script is looping on `while read $line`. Until there's a complete line to read, it doesn't do anything. So, there's no output for you to read. (It's also possible that writing that many bytes to the stdin pipe without checking stdout has overflowed the pipes and blocked somewhere, but forget that for now.)

Comment: @abarnert Ah..yes indeed the `while read line` is waiting for a full line to be read.